# Silverlight 3 File Dialog Box

Tags: silverlight-3.0

Ok - I have a WCF Service which reads an excel file from a certain location and strips the data into an object. What I need is the ability to allow users of my program to Upload an excel sheet to the file location that my Service uses.

Alternitivley I could pass the Uploaded excel sheet to the service directly.

Can anyone help with this. My service code is:

```
    public List<ImportFile> ImportExcelData(string FileName)
    {
        //string dataSource = Location + FileName;
        string dataSource = Location;
        string conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + dataSource.ToString() + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
        var con = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
        con.Open();

        var data = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        var sheetName = data.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "] WHERE Status = '4'", con);
        OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        oleda.SelectCommand = cmd;

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        oleda.Fill(ds, "Employees");
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

        var _impFiles = new List<ImportFile>();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            var _import = new ImportFile();

            _import.PurchaseOrder = row[4].ToString();

            try
            {
                var ord = row[8].ToString();
                DateTime dati = Convert.ToDateTime(ord);
                _import.ShipDate = dati;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                _import.ShipDate = null;
            }


            ImportFile additionalData = new ImportFile();
            additionalData = GetAdditionalData(_import.PurchaseOrder);


            _import.NavOrderNo = additionalData.NavOrderNo;
            _import.IsInstall = additionalData.IsInstall;
            _import.SalesOrderId = additionalData.SalesOrderId;
            _import.ActivityID =  additionalData.ActivityID;
            _import.Subject =  additionalData.Subject ;

            _import.IsMatched = (_import.ShipDate != null & _import.NavOrderNo != "" & _import.NavOrderNo != null & _import.ShipDate > DateTime.Parse("01/01/1999") ? true : false);

            _import.UpdatedShipToField = false;
            _import.UpdatedShipToFieldFailed = false;
            _import.CreateNote = false;
            _import.CreateNoteFailed = false;
            _import.CompleteTask = false;
            _import.CompleteTaskFailed = false;
            _import.FullyCompleted = 0;
            _import.NotCompleted = false;
            _impFiles.Add(_import);

        }


        oleda.Dispose();
        con.Close();
        //File.Delete(dataSource);

        return _impFiles;

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to modify your service to accept a `Stream` instead of a filename, then you can save if off to a file (or parse it directly from the `Stream`, although I don't know how to do that).

Then in your Silverlight app you could do something like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs ev)
{
    var dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    dialog.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm)|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        var fileStream = dialog.File.OpenRead();
        var proxy = new WcfService();
        proxy.ImportExcelDataCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
             MessageBox.Show("Import Data is at e.Result");
             // don't forget to close the stream
             fileStream.Close();
        };
        proxy.ImportExcelDataAsync(fileStream);
    }
}
```

You could also have your WCF service accept a `byte[]` and do something like this.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs ev)
{
    var dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    dialog.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm)|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        var length = dialog.File.Length;
        var fileContents = new byte[length];
        using (var fileStream = dialog.File.OpenRead())
        {
            if (length > Int32.MaxValue)
            {
                throw new Exception("Are you sure you want to load > 2GB into memory.  There may be better options");
            }
            fileStream.Read(fileContents, 0, (int)length);
        }
        var proxy = new WcfService();
        proxy.ImportExcelDataCompleted += (s, e) =>
                                                {
                                                    MessageBox.Show("Import Data is at e.Result");
                                                    // no need to close any streams this way
                                                };
        proxy.ImportExcelDataAsync(fileContents);
    }
}
```

### Update

Your service could look like this:

```
public List<ImportFile> ImportExcelData(Stream uploadedFile)
{
    var tempFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/uploadedFiles/" + Path.GetRandomFileName());
    try
    {
        using (var tempStream = File.OpenWrite(tempFile))
        {
            uploadedFile.CopyTo(tempStream);
        }

        //string dataSource = Location + FileName;
        string dataSource = tempFile;
        string conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + dataSource.ToString() +
                        ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
        var con = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
        con.Open();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (File.Exists(tempFile))
            File.Delete(tempFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure how to do it as a stream - Can only get it working using the above method

Comment: You would have to save the contents of the stream to a local directory on the server.  Somewhere the WCF service account has permission, maybe a subfolder on the website root, or a temp directory.

Comment: Added an update that shows how to take a stream into a tempFile, and run it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Bendewey that was great. Had to amend it slightly -
My Service:

```
        var tempFile = @"c:\temp\" + Path.GetRandomFileName();

        try  
        {        

            int length = 256;
            int bytesRead = 0;
            Byte[] buffer = new Byte[length];

            // write the required bytes
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(tempFile, FileMode.Create))
            {
                do
                {
                    bytesRead = uploadedFile.Read(buffer, 0, length);
                    fs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                while (bytesRead == length);
            }

            uploadedFile.Dispose();             



            string conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + dataSource.ToString() + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
            var con = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
```

Thanks Again for your help

Comment: fyi, 256 is a really small bufffer length, any reason for that?  I'd recommend at least 1024.